# Does an eved canaani who is freed due to physical injury become a full fledged Jew?

Tags: halacha, slave-serve-eved-avadim

If an eved canaani is freed due to physical injury inflicted by his owner, does he become a full fledged Jew as he would if he were freed by his owner for another reason?

Answer (score 1):

I recall from the gemara that the master must write a *get shichrur* for the eved after he has freed him because of the loss of a limb. I have found in gittin 38 the case of an eved who becomes free (without being freed explicitly by his master). I think that the case would also apply as I do not recall where it says so explicitly about the loss of the limb. The example given is

[GIVING A "GET SHICHRUR" TO A SLAVE WHO IS ALREADY FREE](http://www.dafyomi.co.il/gitin/insites/gi-dt-038.htm)

> Rav Shaman bar Aba says in the name of Rebbi Yochanan that an Eved who
>   escapes from prison acquires himself and goes free. Moreover, Beis Din
>   forces his master to write for him a Get Shichrur.
>
> If the Eved goes free as a result of his act of escaping from prison,
>   why is it necessary for his master to give him a Get Shichrur?

The discussion shows that the *get shichrur* is required so that nobody can claim that he is not allowed to marry a Jewish woman. Since he is allowed to marry a Jewish woman, and the *get shichrur* is required as proof of that fact, then we see that the eved is a full fledged Jew.

[Rabbi Gamliel and Tavi](http://rabbiarthursegal.blogspot.com/2009/10/rabbi-arthur-segaltalmud.html)

> [Talmud  Yerushalmi Tractate Ketuboth 23a]. Rabban Gamaliel
>   accidentally knocked out a tooth of his favorite servant, Tavi. He
>   conferred with Rabbi Yehoshu'a, saying, "I think I have found a reason
>   to free my servant, Tavi , because I knocked out one of his teeth and
>   the Torah [Exodus 21:27] requires a master to free a servant who
>   suffered mayhem at his hands). Rabbi Yehoshu'a reminded him that he
>   was only required to do so by law if two competent witnesses testified
>   against him in court. But, of course, Rabban Gamaliel could free Tavi
>   from servitude whenever he wished. However, Tavi did not want to be
>   released. Rabbi Yehoshu'a did not say that Rabban Gamaliel could not
>   free Tavi, only that he did not have to.

However, the implication in that discussion (involving the get shichrur) is that Tavi would be a full fledged Jew had he actually become free.

Comment: Pls explain why you say "the  implication in that discussion is that Tavi would be a full fledged Jew had he actually become free."

Comment: "of course, Rabban Gamaliel could free Tavi from servitude whenever he wished" I don't know why that is true. לעולם בהם תעבודו.

Comment: @DoubleAA  Concerning "whenever he wished":  There is a distinction between having the authority to set a eved canaani free and it being proper to do so.

Comment: @YehudaW I don't usually say "I can skip Keriat Shema in the morning".

Comment: @DoubleAA  The biblical obligation to say the shema is at a much higher level of obligation than the prohibition to manumit.  I think it was Rabbi Gamleil who freed his servant to make a minyan. (In Brachot, perhaps in the mid 20's?)

Comment: @YehudaW Aren't they both Mitzvot Aseh? Do we have a hierarchy for which Mitzvot Aseh are higher than which?

Comment: @DoubleAA I think your statement must be wrong, based on Rabbi Gamleil freeing his servant.

Comment: @DoubleAA I have no source for any of this, but maybe this mitzva is like sukkah and has a heter similar to mitztaer?  You can't go inside/free your servant just because you feel like it, but maybe if you're no longer benefiting from having him as a slave, that's not called תעבדו and you can free him?  Again, it's speculation, based on Rabban Gamliel freeing him.

Comment: @Heshy Not a bad idea. That still is a problem for the OP who said "of course, Rabban Gamaliel could free Tavi from servitude whenever he wished"